# What is the current status of client-side storage in underlying WebViews using a hybride mobile development approach?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, webview

Currently we are aiming on using a hybrid approach to develop cross-plattform mobile Apps. In that project we have to store large amounts of data on the mobile device.

A lot of hybrid frameworks (like Phonegap f.e.) offer access to the local file system to store data. But due to the structure of the used data - which has a lot of relationships and should be searchable and so on - we need an approach that makes SQL-like operations possible.

Using an hybrid approach which uses the WebView as application container (mainly aimed on Windows Phone, Android and iOS) the underlying browser is the component to turn to.

Basically there are three ways to save data persistent on the browser:

- Web Storage - Name:Value-Pairs
- Web SQL - SQL-like
- IndexedDB - Object-Storage

WebStorage is supported on all WebViews but is definitly not suitable due to the reuqirements. WebSQL only seems to be supported by Andorid and iOS (is this correct?). The problem here is the size limit which seems to be 5MB and WindowsPhone is not able to support this. WebSQL is deprecated by W3C as far as I'm concerned. IndexedDB seems to be the new weapon of choice but is only supported by Windows Phone - at least that's what's the [Phonegap-Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) states.

So here are the questions:

1. What are the size limits on the mentioned operating systems in a WebView using the mentioned saving techniques?
2. What is the status of the IndexDB support on the WebViews of the mentioned mobile operating systems?

<s>3. Are there any other suggestions achieving this?</s>

Comment: You could easily find the answer in the documentation of each of the target operating systems. Also asking for suggestion is off-topic it will yield only opinion based answers.

Comment: @rckoenes: Removed third question.